# Date and Time Zone offset

Tags: php, date, timezone

I must use time offset value to change the time. I make it via

```
// serwer time is XYZ Time Zone date time
$date_today_tz = date("Y-m-d H:i");       // actual date time from XYZ time zone 
$time_diff_UTC = date('P');         // diff to UTC                                 
$_time = explode(":",$time_diff_UTC);
$time_diff_UTC_strt = $_time[0]." hours ".$_time[1]." minutes";
and
gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time_diff_UTC_strt, strtotime($date_today_tz)));
```

I have a time from a XYZ time zone and a time offset (to this time) from UTC (f.ex. -07:00)

```
$time_diff_UTC = date('P');
```

But (for another part of my code) I must have the value of this offset but with opposite sign f.ex.

```
-07:00 -> +07:00
+01:00 -> -01:00
ect.
```

As the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
str_replace(array('-','+','#'), array('#','-','+'), $time_diff_UTC)
```

Comment: $time_diff_UTC should return a string, so this would be a simple, yet effective solution. +1